# can not store data in codeigniter session

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am trying to store data in my session variable, but i am doing something wrong obviosly.

I have the following code:

```
       $formValues = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
        echo "Form<pre>";
        print_r($formValues);
        echo "</pre>";
        $this->session->set_userdata($formValues);
        $sessionFormValues = $this->session->userdata('formValues');

        echo "MySess<pre>";
        print_r($sessionFormValues);
        echo "</pre>";

        echo "Sess<pre>";
        print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
        echo "</pre>";
```

The first print_r returns:

```
Array
(
    [addtypeid] => 
    [isnew] => 
    [orderby] => 
    [geographicareaid] => 
    [catid] => 1
    [catid2] => 
    [manufacturerid] => 
    [modelid] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_from] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_to] => 
    [hoursused_from] => 
    [hoursused_to] => 
    [horsepowers_from] => 
    [horsepowers_to] => 
    [price_from] => 
    [price_to] => 
    [colorid] => 
    [isdamaged] => 
 )
```

The second print_r returns just MySess (empty array)

while the third print_r returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => 639ca0b53c8e68cda4e6d61605c4d227
    [ip_address] => 94.68.157.85
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.117 Safari/537.36
    [last_activity] => 1393239192
    [user_data] => 
    [addtypeid] => 
    [isnew] => 
    [orderby] => 
    [geographicareaid] => 
    [catid] => 1
    [catid2] => 
    [manufacturerid] => 
    [modelid] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_from] => 
    [yearofmanufacturing_to] => 
    [hoursused_from] => 
    [hoursused_to] => 
    [horsepowers_from] => 
    [horsepowers_to] => 
    [price_from] => 
    [price_to] => 
    [colorid] => 
    [isdamaged] => 
)
```

Anyone can point me what I am doing variable $sessionFormValues returns an empty array? How can i get only the formvalues data in a separate variable?

Regards, John

Comment: you are sending blank fields from form

Comment: one of them is not blank. field catid has value of 1.

Comment: use print_r($_POST); and then show result here

Comment: i just did that, and the results are 100% the same.

Comment: its mean no data is coming from form.

Comment: please check the catid key and you will see that has a value of 1

Comment: i change the search criteria, and now some keys have the values of 1 as well, but the variable $sessionFormValues is still empty. while the all_userdata show those values.

Comment: use this $sessionFormValues = $this->session->userdata($formValues);
instead of $sessionFormValues = $this->session->userdata('formValues');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is getting saved in the session fine but the problem is that the `'formValues'` key doesn't exist.  You need to change

```
$this->session->set_userdata($formValues);
```

to

```
$this->session->set_userdata('formValues', $formValues);
```

Comment: That worked. Now...how can i get only the $formValues from the session? I am trying with :  echo "Sess<pre>";
            print_r($this->session->userdata($formValues));
            echo "</pre>"; but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Never mind..i found it...$mySessData = $this->session->userdata('formValues');
            print_r($mySessData); did the trick. thanks.